# Opencv video with artifacts and colour issues

Tags: opencv, image-processing, filtering

I am writing an opencv code to fix this particular rgb image ...

[image]

Any inputs on how to fix this image ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add more information, and what you've tried so far. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Fixing video is very different than fixing an image, your title and text tell two different stories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue . .. This was due to an incorrect attribute in the caps properties of in one of my gstreamer pipelines ... Hence, the issue is not related to the opencv side .

Apologies ...